# MySQL 5.7: 'EXPLAIN' takes very long time to execute with a long 'IN' list

Tags: mysql, explain

While issuing `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries to our MySQL DB, we always perform also an `EXPLAIN` query and log its results for debugging purposes.

Some of our queries include an `IN` clause with a long list of values (may be 100K+, against an indexed column). The relevant table holds ~3M rows, there are no joins in these queries.

So, I'm issuing a pair of queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE col0 IN (v0,v1,...,v100000)
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE col0 IN (v0,v1,...,v100000)
```

`col0` is an indexed column of `varchar(100)`.

Now, after upgrading from MySQL 5.5.33 to 5.7.12, I see that while the `SELECT COUNT` query itself works the same way, the `EXPLAIN` queries take a very long time (~45 sec. for a list of 100K values, and looks like the growth is exponential). In version 5.5, it was immediate, like all other `EXPLAIN` queries.

I couldn't find any relevant information in the release notes for recent versions of MySQL.

Does anybody knows: (1) is it a (known) bug or an expected behavior for some reason; (2) is there any way to work around it by configuration flags, etc.?

Thanks in advance!

In both versions, our only additions to the standard `my.cnf` are:

```sh
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G

max_allowed_packet = 104857600 #to make such queries possible from the beginning
```

In version 5.7 I've also added this:

```sh
#Remove the 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES' modes from the list of SQL modes.
sql-mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: For 2, create a temp table and JOIN on it.Also is the config file the same as the old one? buffer_pool etc Show us the EXPLAIN please

Comment: @Mihai, thanks, however the query itself works fine and in reasonable times, so I don't see a reason to change it just because of a problem in `EXPLAIN` (in the worst case I can just omit it in such cases and loose debugging information). The question is whether it can be solved by configuring the DB or something like this.

Comment: Are you saying you do not have this performance degradation when executing the query without `explain`?

Comment: @trincot, please see the updated question - it is a pair of queries, `SELECT` works well, `EXPLAIN SELECT` degrades.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution? @urim